# Checking whether username exists in MySQLi Database and PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, authentication

I have been working on a website which has a xampp server and a database called users with a table called AccountDetails. About a year ago I got it to work perfectly, but the server I was using then required MySQL not MySQLi. Now I have to use MySQLi and can't even get the simplest of sql's SELECT function to work, any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root","", "users");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($link)){
    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo"Connection Successful <br></br>";
}

echo("Check if still working <br></br>");

// -----------------------------//
echo("Its running <br></br>");
$result = $link->query("SELECT ID, UserName FROM AccountDetails");
return $result->result();
var_dump($result);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The Query itself works when I plug it into the phpmyadmin SQL section and it returns the values that I expect it too.

I've spent days looking online for different answers but none of them work, and the var_dump only gives me "bool(false)" which I don't think I should be getting.

Comment: Have you considered securing your website by using prepared statements?

Comment: I have, but currently, I'm just trying to get this to work so I can move forward from there. @TheCodesee

Comment: Even when using `mysql_` you had to process the results of a query with some sort of `fetch`

Comment: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); var_dump($row);` check this instead of `return $result->result();`

Comment: When you wrote this line `return $result->result();` what were you trying to achieve? Baring in mind you dont seem to be in a function

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: I tried your replacement code, "$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); var_dump($row);" @JeesKDenny but to no avail. I was presented with this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Comment: Should we assume that you still have the database in your MySQL Server

Comment: I believe so @RiggsFolly however when I added your other code at the top of my script it gave me, Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'users.accountdetails' doesn't exist in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login.php:14

Comment: Well I would do some checking in MySQL Server. That sounds like your database has gone on holiday without letting you know

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Okay so say I were to restart everything but keep this code, how would I reset up my MySQL Sever with the same db name and table name. Some Possible important info: I'm using Xampp with Apache Websever and MySQL Database.

Comment: Ohh and some more information, I used a INSERT function, and it worked, so I'm not sure why its saying that both the table and the db doesnt exist.

Comment: Maybe its a simple spolling irror on the table name then

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root","", "users");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($link)){
    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo"Connection Successful <br></br>";
}

echo("Check if still working <br></br>");

// -----------------------------//
echo("Its running <br></br>");
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM AccountDetails";
$result = $link->query($sql_select);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "UserName: " . $row['UserName']. "<br>";
}

} else {
    echo "No Records";
}
$link->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why did you just invent a WHERE clause?

Comment: I tried it but it gave me the typical "trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry I forgot if he was fetching records

Comment: @JTBrits Can you test the updated one please and check if it still gives you a same error

Comment: @JTBrits Also double check for the column names and table name you're using in code are matched with your database table and columns `case-sensitive`

Comment: Still trying to get property of non object. @Rtra

Comment: @JTBrits can you please post an error message so i can look through

Comment: @Rtra Sure this is the result: Connection Successful 

Its running 


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login.php on line 27
No Records

Comment: @JTBrits Open your database and then first check for the table name i.e. `AccountDetails` if exists then check for both column names `ID, UserName` and verify they have no issues on case-sensitive or in typo

Comment: You should be careful of using capitalisation in table and column names. Windows is case insensitive, but if you ever come to move this code to a unix server, you may get issues as unix is case sensitive

Comment: Okay, thanks ill change it all to lower case, but I just double checked if my signup code was working which has nearly identical coding, and it still worked, its just that page. All the values for db name and table name were exaclty the same. @RiggsFolly

Comment: @JTBrits Can you please post your `INSERT` statement only from your signup code so I can verify from my end

Comment: $value = $_POST['email'];
   $value2 = $_POST['user'];
   $value3 = $_POST['pass'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO AccountDetails (EmailAdd, UserName, Pwd) VALUES ('$value', '$value2','$value3')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Comment: @JTBrits can you replace line `15` and `19` of my code and put this `$result = $link->query("SELECT UserName FROM AccountDetails");` on line '15` and then `echo "Username: " . $row["UserName"]. "<br>";` on line `19` and test if you get the same error or not

Comment: @JTBrits can you give a try of using `$link->query("SELECT * FROM AccountDetails");`

Comment: @Rtra Same thing.

Comment: I'll be AFK for a while, no more WIfi connection unfortunately.